# Use C to integrate with Google chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, com, integration

I work for a company that creates integrated shipping software. Currently, we are using the Internet Explorer COM interface to be able to get/set field values and execute scripts within the page.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to do this same type of thing with google chrome? Our applications are written in C++ and we need the ability to 1. Get the value of data from fields 2. Set the value of data fields and 3. execute scripts within a currently open chrome window.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I highly doubt it, at least not easily. Can you not write a browser extension instead? Or even a plugin using NPAPI.

Comment: May be this can help you? https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/